# MySQL query with LIMIT and updating data by chunks

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a table in my mysql db with columns `id` and `drivers_license_number`. Now data in `drivers_license_number` column is stored in plaintext, and I want to encrypt it.

This table contains about 400000 records. I have read about problems with LIMIT and OFFSET issue and try to use in my query late row lookups.

So first of all I need to get data from db, then encrypt the right field and update db with this encrypted field. I don't understand, how to organize my code to send parameters with limit and offset to db. I need to work in loop in this situation?

```
function getUpdatedEncryptedField(db_table_name, field_name) {
    return getDataFromDb(db_table_name, field_name).then(function(result){
        return encryptData(result, field_name).then(function (result){
            var promises = result.map(function(item) {
                var data = [item[field_name], item.id];
                return updateFieldNameData(db_table_name, field_name, data);
            });
            return q.all(promises);
        });
    });
}
```

After the first pass I will get for example first 1000 records and how to move forward to get another 1000 rows?

```
function getDataFromDb(db_table_name, field_name, limit, offset) {
    var sql = 'SELECT ds.id, ' + field_name + ' FROM ( SELECT id FROM ' + db_table_name + 'WHERE ' + field_name +
        ' IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id LIMIT ' + limit + ', ' + offset + ') d  JOIN ' + db_table_name + ' ds ON ds.id = d.id ORDER BY ds.id;'
    return db.modio.executeSql(sql);
}
```

Comment: What type is the `id` field into the table ? Is it an autoincrement number or is it mixed number with chars, like e.g. '12bgf1'

Comment: id is auto incremet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a carring/high order function to update the chunks by e.g 1000 and get the next 1000 records until the 400000, like so:

`function getUpdatedEncryptedField(db_table_name, field_name) {
       var idFrom = 0;
       var idTo = 1;
       return function getDataFromDB(db_table_name, field_name){
                idFrom = idTo;
                idTo += 1000;
                console.log(`id range is ${idFrom}-${idTo}`);
                // call your db to get the recods
       }
    }

```
// assign high order func to updateChunks var, which is again a func
var updateChunks = getUpdatedEncryptedField('studentsDB','creditCard')

// so each time you execute updateChunks() the values idFrom & idTo are updated
// updateChunks()
//  id range is 1-1001
// updateChunks()
//  id range is 1001-2001
// and so on

// create a loop until you get all the table records, e.g.
// pay attention to define 'i' with let and not with var because of async loop
for(let i=0; i <= 400000/1000; i++){
   // call the updateChunk func here
   // at eaach itteration it will ask for the next chunk of records
    updateChunks()
 }
```

`

*Of course you should update a little bit your mysql query, to get the range of Ids from - to, this is out of the question scope.*

Hope helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I will try!